# Section Commands Inside Enumerate Environment

Tags: sectioning, enumerate

I would like to have subsection commands both before and inside an `enumerate` environment:

```
\subsection*{Instantaneous Velocity}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item[\textsf{\textbf{Example 1}}] The table below gives the position $s$ of a car at time $t$.

    \begin{enumerate}
         \item Find the average velocity over the following intervals.
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item $0 \leq t \leq 0.4$
            \end{enumerate}
        \item Estimate the instantaneous velocity at $t=0.4$.
    \end{enumerate} 
\vfill

\subsection*{Defining Instantaneous Velocity Using the Idea of a Limit}

        \item[\textsf{\textbf{Example 2}}] Yackety yack yack

    \vfill

\end{enumerate}
```

When I compile this, the subsection inside the `enumerate` environment is indented (clearly, to match the `enumerate` environment) but I would like for it to align with the subsection that is outside of the `enumerate` environment.

I am aware of `\suspend` `\resume` and `\interitemtext`, but was wondering if there might be some simple(er) solution to this, or a basic concept that I might be missing.

Comment: With `\usepackage{mdwlist}` you can `\suspend` an enumeration and then `\resume` it. This may help.

Comment: From the point of the logical structure of a document, is there really a need to have a sectional unit inside a list?

Comment: Why do you want it inside the list if you want it to appear to be outside the list? That is, putting it inside the list essentially tells TeX to format it accordingly and that will typically involve the indentation etc. So I don't understand why you'd want to do that if that's not the effect you desire.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I wanted this construction to mirror the layout of the textbook I am using. In each section of the book, there are multiple subsections, but the number of examples continues through the entire section.

Comment: @Randy Scott: I discover this explanation of your request. My suggestion for such a structure would be to use something like: `\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter]`, whereby the examples would be numbered continuously (if I may say so…) throughout a chapter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a simple solution with the `enumitem`package (no need to manually number the outer enumerate). The idea is just to close the enumerate environment at the end of the subsection and to open another one with the `resume*` option after the beginning of the next section:

```
        \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}

        \usepackage{enumitem}

        \begin{document}

        \subsection*{Instantaneous Velocity}

        \begin{enumerate}[label =\textsf{\textbf{Example \arabic*. }}, wide,labelindent = 0pt]
            \item The table below gives the position $s$ of a car at time $t$.

            \begin{enumerate}
                 \item Find the average velocity over the following intervals.
                    \begin{enumerate}
                        \item $0 \leq t \leq 0.4$
                    \end{enumerate}
                \item Estimate the instantaneous velocity at $t=0.4$.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{enumerate}
        \vfill

        \subsection*{Defining Instantaneous Velocity Using the Idea of a Limit}

        \begin{enumerate}[resume*]

                \item  Yackety yack yack

        \end{enumerate}
        \vfill
        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard! (I know we are not supposed to use comments to say "Thanks," but my Mom taught me better than that!

Comment: http://xkcd.com/859/ )